# RestEasy 3.0.8-Final List Mapping Guice

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

How do I get all mapping in RestEasy 3.0.8 Final with Guice? Can I get list without manually reflection all classes in class loader?

Comment: You don't need to scan all classes but you'll need reflection to get the path-information. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24863148/1353722)

Comment: Not work. List<String> scannedResourceClasses = deployment.getScannedResourceClasses(); is null

Comment: This will of course only work if you configure RESTeasy to scan your resource classes. Maybe `deployment.getResourceClasses()` returns something.